# HP proliant ML370 G4 server

Tags: installation, grub2, hp, mythbuntu

I have an old HP Proliant ML370 G4 server. I tried to install ubuntu (MythBuntu) from USB stick, and after installatin started and logo of Mythbuntu shows up, I got an error

Ubuntu 12.04 .... 37.190396 floppy: 0 invalid for paramater allowed_drive_mask

Does anyone have and idea how to solve this /what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

When the USB stick first starts to boot, edit the default boot options and remove the parameter "floppy.allowed_drive_mask=0"